# Git: format to correctly autocolor %d

Tags: git, colors, git-log

The way I read the [git-log manpage](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#_pretty_formats):

> *%C(…​)*: color specification, as described in color.branch.* config option; adding `auto,` at the beginning will emit color only when colors are enabled for log output (by `color.diff`, `color.ui`, or `--color`, and respecting the auto settings of the former if we are going to a terminal). `auto` alone (i.e. `%C(auto)`) will turn on auto coloring on the next placeholders until the color is switched again.

Then one of the following two formats *should* be the correct way to request colors conditionally (as you'd need to do in a script, alias, or named pretty format) for `%d` and `%D`:

```
--pretty='%C(auto)%d'
--pretty='%C(auto,auto)%d'
```

However, the first format (`%C(auto)%d`) doesn't seem to work, testing with these three commands—first, generating color output with no pager; second, attempting to invoke automatic color suppression by piping to `cat`; finally, explicitly suppressing color (note, you need to have a branch and/or tag checked out to see the color effect, otherwise `%d` outputs nothing):

```
git --no-pager log -5 --pretty='%C(auto)%d %C(auto,blue)%s'
# correctly shows %d dynamically colored and %s blue

git --no-pager log -5 --pretty='%C(auto)%d %C(auto,blue)%s' | cat
# still colored %d, but %s uncolored

git --no-pager log --color=never -5 --pretty='%C(auto) %d %C(auto,blue)%s'
# same: still colored %d, but %s uncolored
```

Trying the second format (`%C(auto,auto)%d`) doesn't work either:

```
git --no-pager log -5 --pretty='%C(auto,auto) %d %C(auto,blue)%s'
error: invalid color value: auto
fatal: unable to parse --pretty format

git --no-pager log -5 --pretty='%C(auto,auto) %d %C(auto,blue)%s' | cat
# correct, no colors

git --no-pager log --color=never -5 --pretty='%C(auto,auto) %d %C(auto,blue)%s'
# correct, no colors
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. What is the correct format sequence to print colorized `%d` and `%D` if and only if the output would ordinarily be colored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first format works like expected in respect of colourised/non-colourised output (at least with v2.11.0).

#### TL;DR

Nevertheless you miss to reset the colour specification, which leads to wrong colours if at the beginning of the next item (if no colour has been set).

Corrected colourspec:

```
%h %C(auto)%d %C(auto,blue)%s%C(auto,reset)
```

Tests:

```
git config pretty.test "%h %C(auto)%d %C(auto,blue)%s%C(auto,reset)"

echo; git --no-pager log -5 --pretty=test
echo; git --no-pager log -5 --pretty=test | cat
echo; git --no-pager log -5 --pretty=test --color=never
```

Comment: Indeed, it was a bug that was fixed between Sep 2015 when this question was asked and Dec 2017 when it was answered. Now if a colourspec is opened and not reset, Git resets it automatically. But for Git at the time before the fix, this would have solved the problem.